# PHP-Unit Selenium moveTo takes no effect

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I got a working setup of phpunit (5.7.23) and selenium standalone web driver (3.7.1) with ChromeDriver (2.29.461571) where I can run tests on.

Sadly I run into the issue that the moveTo-command does not take any effect. So that some Buttons could be found but they are not clickable by the error f.e.

> "Element is not clickable at point (46, 633)"

With "does not take any effect" means that when I look at the screenshots I made, the viewport is the same as on start.

**Example**
($this inherits from PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase)

I am looking for the logout-Button which is an `<a>`-Tag. On the second line I want to move there.

```
$logout_link = $this->byId('nav-logout');
$this->moveto($logout_link);
```

I already tried the moveto-command with offset-settings -- also without any effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down to selenium-standalone 3.6 and now it works ... maybe a bug in the new version.